# Using variables in Model Crud with Advanced Usage with Closure

Tags: php, fuelphp

```
echo $slot->id;
$slot->players = (Model_Players::find(function ($query)
{
    return $query->join('users')
        ->on('players.player', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('players.slot', $slot->id);
})) ?: array();
```

Returns:

```
4

ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: slot  
APPPATH/classes/controller/booking.php @ line 98:  
98: ->where('players.slot', $slot->id);
```

How do I send the `$slot` object into the function?

Comment: Model_Players::find(function ($query) use ($slot)

Comment: That only bloody worked! Do you want to add that as an answer so I can give you some sweet Reputation points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `use`.

```
Model_Players::find(function ($query) use ($slot)
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to "use" the $slot variable in the query

```
echo $slot->id;
$slot->players = (Model_Players::find(function ($query) use ($slot)
{
    return $query->join('users')
        ->on('players.player', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('players.slot', $slot->id);
})) ?: array();
```